# Parse Nested JSON in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Below is my JSON. I need to get the `'id'` value which is nested inside.

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "total": 142250,
      "_id": "BC",
      "test": [
        {
          "id": "sample"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "total": 210.88999999999996,
      "_id": "USD"
    },
    {
      "total": 1065600,
      "_id": "TK"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using the below code for nested. but getting the below error

```
response = response.replace("'", '"')
response = json.loads(response)
for doc in response['result']:
    print(doc['_id'], doc['total'])
docs = response['result']
for doc1 in docs['test']:
    print(doc1['id'])
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 34, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `test` is a **list**, not a **dictionary** as your code treats it.

```py
response = response.replace("'", '"')
response = json.loads(response)
for doc in response['result']:
    print(doc['_id'], doc['total'])
    for test_doc in doc['test']:
       print(test_doc['id'])
```